# phpunit test - validation for store boolean fields which fills by non-boolean and invalid value

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit, laravel-10

sorry for my bad english :) .

I want to test a boolean field validation error, when user entered a non-boolean value (from browser inspection,for example) .

for example, if in browser inspect, I set 'is_bulk' to 'test' string, I get the error in UI correctly,

[image]

but in phpunit, non-boolean value is turned to Boolean value.
and then store will be done successfully, with no Errors !
so I can't test validation error for boolean attributes of a model.

this is my test method in PHPUnit :

```
public function test__boolean_is_bulk()
    {
        $product =  Product::factory()->dataToSaveByRoute()->make(['is_bulk' => 'test']);

        $response = $this->loginAs(static::$user)->post(route('store',  $product->toArray()));

        $response->assertInvalid('is_bulk')
            ->assertStatus(302);
    }
```

I expect the test is passed, but product will save correctly, and $response returns 200 for status.
and no validation error happens.

I got dd, and it returns true!

```
dd($product['is_bulk']);   //->returns true
```

also below code returns true:

```
dd($product->is_bulk);
```

and this assertion is true, too :

```
$this->assertIsBool($product['is_bulk']);
```

this code returns 'is_bulk' equals true

```
dd($product->toArray());
```

> "quantity" => null
> "is_bulk" => true
> "status" => 3
> "creator_user" => null

============================================

how sholud I write my test function?

Comment: I found is_bulk has been changed from 'test' to true, because of using factory and producing a Product Model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found is_bulk has been changed from 'test' to true, because of using factory and producing a Product Model.
model casting, casts 'test' to boolean value.

now, I get array from product made, then change is_bulk to 'test', then go to 'store' route.

everything is ok now.

```
/**
     * @test       
     */
    public function form_validation_boolean_fields()
    {
        $product =  Product::factory()->dataToSaveByRoute()->make();
        $productArr = $product->toArray();
        $productArr['is_bulk'] = 'test';
       
        $response = $this->loginAs(static::$user)->post(route('store',  $productArr));

        $response->assertInvalid(['is_bulk'])
            ->assertStatus(302);
    }
```